# My portScanner program fails after entering any IP address

Tags: python, port-scanning

this is my code:

```
import socket

target = input("enter ip addressd to scan: " )
portrange = input ("enter port range 5-200: " )

lowport = int(portrange.split("-")[0])
highport = int(portrange.split("-")[1])

print ('scanning host', target, 'from port',lowerport , 'to port', highport )

for port in range(lowport,highport):
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    status = s.connect_ex(target, port)
    if (status == 0):
        print ('**port', port, ' -open**')

    else:
        print('port--',port,' --closed')
    s.close()
```

I keep getting this error when executing the code from my terminal and entering an IP address

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "portScan.py", line 3, in <module>
  target = input ("enter ip address to scan: " )
File "<string>", line 1



SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

help???

Comment: what is the python version that you use?

Answer (score 0):

You're probably using python2. The Python v2 `input` function doesn't do what you seem to think it should do. From `pydoc2.7 input`:

```
input(...)
    input([prompt]) -> value

    Equivalent to eval(raw_input(prompt)).
```

Notice the `eval()`. That causes Python to evaluate whatever was input as if it is valid Python code. This behavior was changed in Python v3 so that it no longer `eval`'s the input.

Don't use Python v2. Use Python v3. If you absolutely have to use that ancient version you should be using `raw_input`. Also, there are other, more serious, problems with your program. Port scanners have been written many, many, times. Don't reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score -1):

*Try This After correcting your code :*

```
import socket

target = input("enter ip addressd to scan: " )
portrange = input("enter port range 5-200: " )

lowerport = int(portrange.split("-")[0])
highport = int(portrange.split("-")[1])

print ('scanning host', target, 'from port',lowerport , 'to port', highport )

for port in range(lowerport,highport):
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    status = s.connect_ex((target,port))
    if (status == 0):
        print ('**port', port, ' -open**')

    else:
        print('port--',port,' --closed')
    s.close()
```

your errors was in typing:
input() not input ()
and the variable lowerport sometimes you name it lowerport and sometimes lowport
finally:
status = s.connect_ex(target, port)
need to be like this s.connect_ex((target, port))
because it use tuples not strings
I hope that will be helpful for you.

Comment: You didn't explain what was causing the original syntax error.

Comment: the original syntax error may causing by your python version try from  your terminal to type: python3 portScan.py

Comment: You did not answer my, implied, question. The problem is that the syntax error is due to the text read by the Python v2.x `input()` function not being valid Python code. Your answer implies the problem  is due to irrelevant issues like the whitespace in the `input (` function call.

Comment: sorry that's because i'm not good on English so maybe i'm not totally understanding your problem.
anyway you have to try using raw_input instead of input. that's my solution